# How can I sort this array using the iComparable compareTo method?

Tags: c#

I have to compare an array of different students so it gives an output of:

Bloggs, John (Bachelor of Engineering) Grade: 6
Smith, John (Bachelor of Engineering) Grade: 6
Bloggs, John (Bachelor of Engineering) Grade: 7
Smith, John (Bachelor of Engineering) Grade: 7
Bloggs, John (Bachelor of IT) Grade: 6
Smith, John (Bachelor of IT) Grade: 6
Bloggs, John (Bachelor of IT) Grade: 7
Smith, John (Bachelor of IT) Grade: 7
Bloggs, Jane (Bachelor of Engineering) Grade: 6
Smith, Jane (Bachelor of Engineering) Grade: 6
Bloggs, Jane (Bachelor of Engineering) Grade: 7
Smith, Jane (Bachelor of Engineering) Grade: 7
Bloggs, Jane (Bachelor of IT) Grade: 6
Smith, Jane (Bachelor of IT) Grade: 6
Bloggs, Jane (Bachelor of IT) Grade: 7
Smith, Jane (Bachelor of IT) Grade: 7

My output is similar to this but I need it to compare it from the bottom up instead.

I can't use an array.Reverse method as the main method of my code will not be called. I need my compareTo method to sort this so that I get these results:

First names in descending order, followed by...
Degrees in ascending order, followed by...
Grades in ascending order, followed by...
Last names in ascending order.

The main method runs an array.Sort

I have tried to rearrange my compareTo() method a few times but it wont put these values in the correct order.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentGradeOrder
{
    class Student : IComparable
    {

        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string degree;
        private int grade;

        /*Implementation of Parameterized constructor */
        public Student(string firstName, string lastName, string degree, int grade)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.degree = degree;
            this.grade = grade;

        }

        /*Implementation of ToString method */
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0} , {1}, {2} Grade {3}", lastName, firstName, degree, grade);
        }

        /*Implementation of CompareTo method */
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {

            Student studentObject = (Student)obj;

            var firstnameofStudent = studentObject.firstName.CompareTo(firstName);
            if (firstnameofStudent == 0)
            {
                var degreeValue = studentObject.degree.CompareTo(degree);
                if (degreeValue == 0)
                {
                    var gradeValue = studentObject.grade.CompareTo(grade);
                    if (gradeValue == 0)
                    {
                        var lastnameofStudent = studentObject.lastName.CompareTo(lastName);
                        if (lastnameofStudent == 0)

                            return lastnameofStudent;
                    }
                    return gradeValue;
                }
                return degreeValue;
            }
            return firstnameofStudent;
        }
```

Comment: It is easier, more flexible and more efficient to implement a [Comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) than implement the IComparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two errors here:
1. When returning firstnameofStudent, it should be multiplied by -1 to achieve descending order
2. There is no need to compare lastnameofStudent to 0 before returning, you don't have further field comparison

Answer (score 0):

If you just want reversed order, you can wrap the `CompareTo` method and return the reversed result.

1. Rename `CompareTo` to other name like `InternalCompareTo`
2. Implement new `CompareTo` method that returns reversed result:

   ```
   public int CompareTo(object obj)
   {
       var result = InternalCompareTo(obj)
       if(result > 0)
           return -1;
       else if(result < 0)
           return 1;
       return 0;
   }
   ```